# Update CheckBox and change corresponding listitem

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to achieve the following:

Functionality of  the `IsDeleteBtnShow` property in the `MyViewModel` is to  display a delete icon if any of the item's checkbox is true. However, since property of checkbox accessible in the `ListViewModel`, I need to pass this update from `ListViewModel` to `MyViewModel`.

However I am getting null exception in the `ListItemViewModel`. But when I call `ListItemViewModel` constructor `parent` is not null. I wonder what I am doing wrong?

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
 public class MyViewModel:MvxViewModel
 {

    private ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> _myListViews;

    public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> MyListViews
    {
        get { return _myListViews; }
        set
        {
            _myListViews= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyListViews);
        }
    }

    private bool _isDeleteBtnShow = false;
    public bool IsDeleteBtnShow
    {
        get {
            return _isDeleteBtnShow;
        }
        set {
            _isDeleteBtnShow = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsDeleteBtnShow);
        }
    }

    public void Init(string myId)
    {
         List<ListItemViewModel> allListItems = new List<ListItemViewModel>();
         allListItems = _myService.GetAllItems(myId);

         foreach (var myTest in allListItems)
         {
           _myListViews.Add(ListItemViewModel.CreateViewModel(myTest));
         }
        ListItemViewModel obj = new ListItemViewModel(this);

      }
   }
```

**ListItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class ListItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    private bool _isChecked;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    readonly MyViewModel _parent;

    public ListItemViewModel()
    {
        // parameterless constructor
    }

    public ListItemViewModel(MyViewModel parent)
    {
      // _parent is not null here
        _parent = parent;
    }

   public static ListItemViewModel CreateViewModel(Test entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new ListItemViewModel
        {
            Date = entity.Date,
            IsSelected = entity.IsSelected,
         };
    }

     public ICommand CheckBoxSelectionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                var isChecked = IsSelected;
                // the following _parent is null
                _parent.IsDeleteBtnShow = true;
            });
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: _once user change it, I would like to update_ - do you mean when the ViewModel comes back from the user, via the framework you're using? And is that calling the required constructor, or the default one?

Comment: `IsDeleteBtnShow` property in the `MyViewModel` is to display or hide delete icon if any of the item's checkbox is true or false correspondingly. However, since property of checkbox accessible in the `ListViewModel`, I need to pass this update from `ListViewModel` to `MyViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you use parameterless constructor of `ListItemViewModel` when you call `CreateViewModel` to create the view model.

You need to add `MyViewModel` parameter to it and pass the view model when creating `ListItemViewModel`:

```
     List<ListItemViewModel> allListItems = new List<ListItemViewModel>();
     allListItems = _myService.GetAllItems(myId);

     foreach (var myTest in allListItems)
     {
          _myListViews.Add(ListItemViewModel.CreateViewModel(this, myTest));
     }
```

and in `ListItemViewModel`:

```
    public static ListItemViewModel CreateViewModel(MyViewModel parent, Test entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new ListItemViewModel(parent)
        {
            Date = entity.Date,
            IsSelected = entity.IsSelected,
        };
    }
```

Comment: `CreateViewModel` takes only one argument.

Comment: give me 5 min please, I am now rebuilding and deploying the solution to the XAP.